# GraphQL: Multi-staged query and reuse response from previous stages

Tags: graphql

I have some GQL queries that depend on their execution on other queries. I am looking for the idiomatic way to do it using GQL syntax.
I have for example two queries, "address" and "contact", each of which requires a token value. This value is retrieved from another query, "info". See below:

```
query($request: TokenRequest!)  {
    info(request: $request) {
      token
    }
}

query($query: InfoQuery!, $token: String)  {
    address(query: $query) {
      response
    }
    contact  {
      email
    }
}
```

Instead of having two separate calls, is there a way to make all of these calls in one place instead of two? This will also require reusing the value gotten from "info" in order for the ither queries to work.

Comment: You'd have to create a single query that internally uses the intermediate token and then returns the address and contact info. There is no piping of results in gql.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. I was hoping if I can find a better way.

Comment: Sorry, not a feature of the language ;)